# cannot get cookies that is set from backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, nestjs

My frontend is running on localhost:3000 while backend which is on nestjs is running on localhost:3006. When user signs up or logs in then I have set cookie in the following way

```
const setCookie = context.res.cookie('cookie-data', {
      accessToken: token.accessToken,
      refreshToken: token.refreshToken,
      user: user,
    });
```

Now, I need this cookie to authenticate each route. I mean if I go to particular page which is a private page then I need to check if those token exist and is valid or not from cookie by calling api for that particular user through the token I get from cookie. If it's valid then allow user to navigate to that page otherwise redirect user to login.

This is how I am trying to get the cookie that's set from backend while user logs in

**_app.tsx**

```
function MyApp({ router, pageProps, Component, cookies }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {
        Component.auth ?
          <Auth cookies={cookies}>
            <Component key={router.route} {...pageProps} />
          </Auth> :
          <Component key={router.route} {...pageProps} />
      }
    </>
  )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  let cookies = {};
  if (process.browser === false) {
    cookies = appContext.ctx.req?.cookies;
  } else {
    cookies = Cookies.get();
  }

  return { ...appProps, cookies }
}
```

export default MyApp

The problem is `appContext.ctx.req?.cookies;` returns an empty object. How can I receive cookie that is set from backend(nestjs) ?

Comment: @Serenity Do you see the cookies present on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
cookies = appContext.ctx.req.headers?.cookie;
```

Comment: Using `appContext.ctx.req.cookies` (like OP did) would also work if the cookies were present.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are parsing the cookie from request with `cookie-parser`, to get a get a cookie you need to parse them, this info is from the [nestjs documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies):

> ```
> npm i cookie-parser 
> npm i -D @types/cookie-parser
> ```
>
> Once the installation is complete, apply the cookie-parser middleware
> as global middleware (for example, in your main.ts file).
>
> ```
> import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
> // somewhere in your initialization file
> app.use(cookieParser());
> ```